# scrolling content div with browser scrollbar (css/jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar

Layout:

http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/9243/scrollcontent.png

The **pink area** is the page layout.

The **black area** should always stay right below the orange area.

So, for example, when the height of the orange area is only 200px, instead of the 600px (as shown on the picture above), the black area would still be right below the orange area at 200px, and not 600px.

And what I want to do now is, when I move the **window scrollbar** I want the content in the **orange area** to scroll first (the orange area should not have scrollbars!). And as soon as I hit the bottom of the content in the orange area I can scroll down the regular page again.

Does anoyne know how to do this? I hope it's not too confusing.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{
    background-color:#c3c3c3;
}
.layout{
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:30px 0px;
    width:900px;
    height:3000px;
    background-color:#f09;
}
.orange_area{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:500px;
    max-height:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#ff7f27;
}
.black_area{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#000;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        //...
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="layout">
<div class="orange_area"><div class="content"></div></div>
<div class="black_area"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that orange area is rendered **above** page content? Like an Ad? And you'd like your ad to be scrolled first (if it's higher than window client height) and when you get to the bottom, the page would start scrolling... Before that, page content should not scroll behind the orange Ad. Is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: yup, that's exactly what I'm trying to do here :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the understanding of the problem, you won't be able to trick the body scrollbar (the one displayed as window scrollbar) to move and not to move its content.

### But a possible trick you could try

When you show the ad, set body `overflow:hidden;` which should hide the default body scrollbars. But you should put your ad into a transparent container that takes the whole size of the window client area and put ad in it.

When the ad would exceed it's height a scrollbar would be shown in place of the window scrollbar. So it would look as if it's the body scrollbar.

**But** you will have a problem when you scroll to the bottom of the ad. This would mean that scroll position would be set at the bottom. At that point you should switch scrollbars again... But body scrollbar would be at the top position since content wasn't scrolled yet.

I don't think this can be done in a user-friendly way. At least not with default scrollbars.

### Custom scrollbar controls

You could provide your own scrollbar control (`position:fixed;height:100%;right:0;`) and use that to scroll your content as you wish. But it's up to you to decide whether that's feasible.